# Set JTextArea value from another class

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

My question is this: How can I set the value of a `JTextArea` from another class? This is the class that contains the `JTextArea` and extends `JFrame`:

```
public class JTreeFiles extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;

public JTreeFiles() {
    initComponents();
}
public JTextArea setTextArea(){
    return this.jTextArea1;
 }
}
```

This where I am trying to set the value of the `JTextArea`:

```
 tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        TreePath tp = tree.getSelectionPath();
        if (tp != null) {
            Object filePathToAdd = tp.getLastPathComponent();
            //System.out.println(filePathToAdd);
            if (filePathToAdd instanceof FileTreeNode) {
                FileTreeNode node = (FileTreeNode) filePathToAdd;
                File file = node.getFile();

                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".java")) {

                        JTreeFiles jf = new JTreeFiles();
                        jf.setTextArea().setText("Text Here"); //Nothing happen here

                }
            }
         }
        }
    }
```

But nothing happens, the text not displayed in the `JTextArea`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you never init the jTextArea1 (from what I can see). You also don't use jTextArea1 anywhere in the listener. You might want to add these and test it.

You have not changed anything in this method

```
public JTextArea setTextArea(){
    return this.jTextArea1;
}
```

This method needs to include something like

```
jTextArea1.setText("sometext");
```

**EDIT**

For example

```
public class JTreeFiles extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea jTextArea1;

    public void setText(String text){
        jTextArea1.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Then you would put this in the listener

```
tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        // All of your other IF statements
        JTreeFiles jf = new JTreeFiles();
        jf.setText("Text Here");
        jf.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah in the method just called the jTextAarea then will use to set text in another class. can you give me please full code about your suggestion?

Comment: Why is everyone calling repaint() after setting the text? That will not fix the issue-

Comment: People are using repaint because it could potentially be an issue. I ran into issues of JComponents not being drawn properly that could be fixed with repaint. It is always good to try every option anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try to redraw the textArea after updating it:

```
jf.getTextArea().update(jf.getTextArea().getGraphics());
```

BTW, according to the beans' code conventions, the JTreeFiles method should be `getTextArea` instead of `setTextArea`.

Comment: cannot find symbol: getTextArea, where is the code should placed?

Comment: This is not the problem, there is clearly to reference to the JTextArea instance. It is just created and forgotten.

Comment: @Stephan True! Often, the most obvious errors are unnoticed :-)